# ¿Cómo acceder a las propiedades de un objeto mediante Indizadores?

Tags: c#

Que tal
tengo un problema que espero me puedan ayudar:
Tengo que declarar un indizador para acceder a las propiedades de una clase Persona...
todavia no entiendo del todo bien el manejo de los indizadores, asi que se me complicó. este es el codigo:

```
using System;
namespace Practica_06___Ej_02
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Persona P = new Persona("Dante", 31528328, 'M', Convert.ToDateTime("15/02/1985"));

            Console.WriteLine(P.Nombre);

            P.Nombre = "Dante MOLFESE"; //probando modif de propiedad

            Console.WriteLine(P.Nombre);
            Console.WriteLine(P.Dni);
            Console.WriteLine(P.Sexo);
            Console.WriteLine(P.Nac);
            Console.WriteLine(P.Edad);


            P[0] = "Dante Molfese";     //probando modif de propiedad mediante indizador
            Console.WriteLine(P[0]);

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

    }

    class Persona
    {
        private int edad;
        private DateTime fechaNac;
        private char sexo;
        private string nombre;
        private int dni;

        private int[] vec;

        public Persona(string nom, int doc, char sex, DateTime nac ){
            nombre = nom;
            dni = doc;
            sexo = sex;
            fechaNac = nac;

            vec = new int[4];

        }

        //Indizador ...........................................................
        public int this[int indice]
        {
               get
               {
                   return vec[indice];
               }
               set
               {
                   vec[indice] = value;
               }
        }


        //Propiedades .........................................................
        public string Nombre{
            get{
                return nombre;
            }
            set{
                nombre = value;
            }
        }

        public char Sexo{
            get{
                return sexo;
            }
            set{
                sexo = value;
            }
        }

        public int Dni{
            get{
                return dni;
            }
            set{
                dni = value;
            }
        }

        public DateTime Nac{
            get{
                return fechaNac;
            }
            set{
                fechaNac = value;
            }
        }

        public int Edad{
            get{
                TimeSpan a = DateTime.Today.Subtract(fechaNac);
                double b = a.Days / 365.25;
                edad = Convert.ToInt32(b);

                return edad;
            }
        }   

    }**texto en negrita**
}
```

Comment: Hola DMolf, olvidaste colocar cual era tu pregunta

Comment: No puedo hacerlo funcionar.

Comment: No se como establecer los indices del indizador a cada propiedad. Por ejemplo, cuando intento modificar el nombre usando el indice 0, me dice que no acepta un string. esto me pasa en el main en la instruccion:  
P[0] = "Dante Molfese";     //probando modif de propiedad mediante indizador

Comment: No has colocado un enunciado o una pregunta jubnto con tu código. Por lo que puedo ver tu indexer devuelve enteros, no se porque estas tratando de asignarle un string `P[0] = "Dante Molfese";`. Además una clase como Persona no tiene mucho sentido que sea indexada, si lo que estas tratando de hacer es acceder a las propiedades: Nombre, Dni, etc , no uses indexers sino usa directamente las propiedades.

Comment: claro. yo lo que quiero es que con P[0] = "asas" ,modifique la propiedad nombre. con P[1]  el dni y asi con todas las propiedades

Comment: Se que es mejor acceder a las propiedades directamente, pero es un trabajo practico y me piden que tambien se pueda acceder a las propiedades mediante indizadores

Comment: Por favor no hagas eso, no tiene sentido, ya que el código necesario para hacer eso va realmente en contra de un buen diseño. En C# las propiedades de un objeto no esán disponibles por índice sino por nombre. La idea de un indexer es mostrar la clase como si esta en sí misma fuera una colección o un arreglo. Acceder a las propiedades mediangte un índice numérico no tiene sentido. Pero si de todas maneras quiere el código (me arrepentiré de escribirlo) espera un poco ahorota pongo la solución

Comment: Dale, gracias. si, me piden hacerlo asi..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionaba en el comentario este diseño no tiene sentido y contradice la utilizadad de tener propiedades strongly-typed en C# así que por favor no des jamás este codigo como respuesta, sin embargo vale la pena entender porque no es un buen diseño pero sin embargo sí es factible. He incluido este código con todas las validacciones que deb tener para esta completo.

**Por favor no uses este código. Ya me arrepentí de haberlo escrito yo mismo.**

```
void Main()
{
    Persona P = new Persona("Dante", 31528328, 'M', Convert.ToDateTime("15/02/1985"));

    Console.WriteLine(P.Nombre);

    P.Nombre = "Dante MOLFESE"; //probando modif de propiedad

    Console.WriteLine(P.Nombre);
    Console.WriteLine(P.Dni);
    Console.WriteLine(P.Sexo);
    Console.WriteLine(P.Nac);
    Console.WriteLine(P.Edad);


    P[0] = "Dante Molfese";     //probando modif de propiedad mediante indizador
    Console.WriteLine(P[0]);
}



class Persona
{
    // Estas propiedades ya no tiene sentido puesto que ya no vas a almacenarlos aquí sino en un vec
    // private int edad; 
    // private DateTime fechaNac;
    // private char sexo;
    // private string nombre;
    // private int dni;

    // vec debe ser de tipp object[] ya que debe poder recibir varios tipos de datos, además puede incializarse directamente
    private object[] vec = new object[4];

    public Persona(string nom, int doc, char sex, DateTime nac)
    {
        vec[0] = nom;
        vec[1] = doc;
        vec[2] = sex;
        vec[3] = nac;
    }

    // El indexer debe ser de tipo object ya que devuelve diferentes tipos de datos
    public object this[int indice]
    {
        get
        {
            // Se deben validar los índices de lo contrario estarías fuera del rango de las propiedades
            ValidarIndice(indice);

            return vec[indice];
        }
        set
        {
            // Se deben validar los índices de lo contrario estarías fuera del rango de las propiedades
            ValidarIndice(indice);

            // Se debe validar individualmente cada indice con su tipo permitido
            var tipos = new [] { typeof(String), typeof(int), typeof(char), typeof(DateTime) };

            if (value.GetType() != tipos[indice])
                throw new ArgumentException("El tipo esperado no es el correcto"); 

            vec[indice] = value;
        }
    }

    private static void ValidarIndice(int indice)
    {
        if (indice < 0 || indice > 3)
            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("indice debe estar entre 0 y 3");
    }

    public string Nombre
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)vec[0]; // Se debe castear de object a string
        }
        set
        {
            vec[0] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Dni
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)vec[1]; // Se debe castear de object a int
        }
        set
        {
            vec[1] = value;
        }
    }

    public char Sexo
    {
        get
        {
            return (char)vec[2]; // Se debe castear de object a char
        }
        set
        {
            vec[2] = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime Nac
    {
        get
        {
            return (DateTime)vec[3]; // Se debe castear de object a DateTime
        }
        set
        {
            vec[3] = value;
        }
    }

    public int Edad
    {
        get
        {
            TimeSpan a = DateTime.Today.Subtract(Nac);
            double b = a.Days / 365.25;
            return Convert.ToInt32(b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por el codigo! se que va en contra de todo, pero es lo que me pedian. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionan arriba es un mal diseño y no tiene mucho sentido. En cualquier caso seria algo asi declarando como el vector como string:

```
private string[] vec;

    //Indizador ...........................................................
    public string this[int indice]
    {
        get
        {
            return vec[indice];
        }
        set
        {
            vec[indice] = value;

            switch (indice)
            {
                case 0:
                    this.nombre = value;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.dni = int.Parse(value);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    this.sexo = value.ToCharArray()[0];
                    break;
                case 3:
                    this.fechaNac = DateTime.Parse(value);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: No esta bien almacenar los valores como `string` por dos motivos: Rendimiento del método `Parse` vs un `cast` y que no estás indicando la cultura en ninguno de los métodos `Parse`. En todo caso mejor almecénalos como object

Comment: No los almacenaría como object ya que entonces estas delegando la responsabilidad de la conversión en quien los consume y por tanto tendría que conocer el tipo de dato que contiene cada elemento del array y esto ademas puede cambiar.

Comment: No a quien los consume,  sino que uses cast en lugar de parse en los case,  y por su puesto validar los tipos de datos